# How to Make A Side-Slide Menu-Type Thing with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, menu

Don't really know what they're called. For some reason I can't remember. But you know on many homepages they have that menu-like thing with panels that slide by showing their products? I pretty much need to learn how to do that, although what I'm actually doing is making a panel slide by when you click some text. The ideas are pretty much the same, from what I can tell, except those menus do it automatically every couple seconds.

Now I know pretty much exactly what to do in terms of the Javascript. The problem I'm having right now is (worryingly) basic HTML. This is what I've got:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dat Sliding Menu Doe</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="slidingmenu.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="menu1">
        <h1>This is some text.</h1>
        <p>This is some more text.</p>
    </div>

    <div id="menu2">
        <h3>This text is different.</h3>
        <h1>Very different.</h1>
        <p>So different, in fact, that</p>
        <p>the div is a different height.</p>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#menu1 {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #d8d808;
    color: white;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0%;
}

#menu2 {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    background: #7feaa8;
    color: white;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 100%;

}
```

Pay no attention to the colors or anything, this is just practice!

It's doing everything it's supposed to do EXCEPT for the fact that I get a scrollbar at the bottom of the page that allows me to scroll to the right and see the second div... which is a problem. Am I doing something fundamentally wrong, or do I just need to add something to get rid of that scrollbar?

Also, a little bit of uncertainty on the Javascript. How would I get it so that the margin-left for both divs changes at EXACTLY the same time? Even a slight delay will show up, right?

It may be easier to just link to a tutorial. I tried researching this, but I didn't know what to look up (forgot what they're called!).

**EDIT**

Ok, so I took Joshua Chavanne's suggestion and hid the overflow for the body, which worked. Then I did all this with the Javascript:

```
var menu1 = document.getElementById("menu1");
var menu2 = document.getElementById("menu2");
var switch1 = document.getElementById("switch1");
var switch2 = document.getElementById("switch2");

switch1.onclick = move;
switch2.onclick = move;

function move() {
    if (menu1.style.marginLeft == 0) {
        show2();
    }
    else {
        show1();
    }
}

function show2() {
    if (menu1.style.marginLeft > -100) {
        menu1.style.marginLeft = (menu1.style.marginLeft - 10) + "px";
        requestAnimationFrame(show2);
    }
}
```

When I click on switch1, menu1 moves over 10px, then stops moving. No idea why.

Comment: I think you are looking for a carousel

Comment: Try putting overflow hidden on the body.

Comment: Not a carousel, more a slideshow. Check the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [free jssor carousel](http://www.jssor.com/download.html)
It will do everything you are asking for and you don't have to write it yourself.

Comment: No, my goal is to learn how to write it myself. Check the edit.